# How to allow users to install multiple copies of an MSI file?

Tags: windows-installer

I want to allow my users to install multiple copies of my application on a single PC; one for testing purposes and one for a production system. The install is an MSI file created directly in Visual Studio 2005. Is there any way to enable this?

I am up for using other tools to generate the install or even using [Ocra.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) directly if I had to, but for now at least [InstallShield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InstallShield) is out of the question.

Comment: Don't test on production servers; or: Don't run live from test servers.

Comment: In a perfect world that is what customers would do.  But in a world were customers are small and want to minimize the number of servers they have to manage, running both on the same server is not unreasonable.

Comment: No one is even talking about severs here.  He's talking about users installing two versions of a product on their own PCs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As slugster has stated, you need to update the ProductCode in the Property table. You will also need to change the package code in the [Summary Stream Information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369794(VS.85).aspx).
The easiest way to modify your MSI is by using automation with [VBScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368562(VS.85).aspx).

The Windows Installer SDK contains useful [scripts](http://www.myitforum.com/inc/arts/2497msiscripts.zip) ([WiRunSQL.vbs](http://www.koders.com/noncode/fid9C9C2D7366257C7CD2F39E21D97397EB035201BE.aspx),  WiSumInf.vbs) that will allow modify your MSI as follows:

To change the product code

```
cscript WiRunSQL.vbs your.msi "UPDATE Property SET Value='{AAAAAAAA-BBB1-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEEEEEEEEE}' WHERE Property='ProductCode'"
```

To change the package code:

```
cscript WiSumInf.vbs your.msi 9={AAAAAAAA-BBB2-CCCC-DDDD-EEEEEEEEEEEE}
```

Just note the new codes should be a valid unique [GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368767(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Just updating the product code does not appear to be enough.  When I do this and run the new MSI, it prompts to repair/remove the previous instance.  I want it to install a new instance.  Any idea what else I need to change to get this to work?

Comment: You should indeed update the package code too. See my updated answer above.

Comment: This suggests that the MSI data needs to be updated everytime the installer is started (so you can install multiple copies of the same product). How does one do this at runtime?

Comment: @rboy note this is 9 year old thead. You shouldn't change any Id on runtime. if that's your requirement then MSI isn't the solution.

Comment: Thanks. So basically if  project is using a legacy setup MSI installer it’s not possible to have it install more than once on a single machine?

Comment: @rboy Right. MSI designed to install an application per user or machine with support for updates\hotfixes. You can however use the configuration property (debug\release etc.) to release different flavors of you application.

Answer (score 2):

You need to author a transform (.mst), which is applied to the [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) file before it runs. This transform can do various things, including changing the product code. It is this changing of the product code which allows more than one instance of the same product to be installed, because to the Windows installer it looks to be a different product.

This transform functionality is native to the Windows installer engine. In other words, you can author these files yourself, products like [InstallShield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InstallShield) just make it easier. Other MSI creation products will likely have the same functionality so you could shop around, and there is likely to be a tool in the Windows Installer SDK to do it (I haven't actually looked, I just use InstallShield).

You can use *[Windows Installer Guide, Database Transforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368260%28VS.85%29.aspx)* to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the Microsoft documentation on [Installing Multiple Instances of Products and Patches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369523(VS.85).aspx).

From memory there was discussion [on the WiX list](http://n2.nabble.com/wix-users-f687560.html) last month with someone trying to do this when using WiX to install multiple websites on the same server. If you can find the relevant threads there should be some more through responses than mine there :)