# How to create a setup project that supports multiple instances (multiple installing)?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, web-deployment-project

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, and I have created a project which I'm trying to install using the setup from Visual Studio 2010. How do I installed it multiple times?

I didn't find the answer on the web. I have read some documents about orca and transform but not an understandable example.

Comment: Can you more elaborate it little bit confusing.If once you create setup then you can install it many times...Or you want to create modules of setup files?

Comment: I need to be able to install the same msi number of times on the same computer, meaning number of instances with are working side by side.
currently the setup will not allow me to install more then one.

Comment: This has been asked before, you can [find it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732220/how-to-allow-users-to-install-multiple-copies-of-an-msi-file/1732404#1732404). [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732220/how-to-allow-users-to-install-multiple-copies-of-an-msi-file/1732404#1732404) explains what you need to do, and the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732220/how-to-allow-users-to-install-multiple-copies-of-an-msi-file/1739513#1739513) tells you how to do it with VBScript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to allow users to install multiple copies of an msi file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732220/how-to-allow-users-to-install-multiple-copies-of-an-msi-file)

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 Other than the fact these are quite old questions & comments, it sure is a duplicate. Duplicates don't have to be worded the exact same way - both questions are asking how to use VS to install an MSI multiple times on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

In project property you will see a property called UPGRADECODE Generate a new code and proceed with build and you can now able to install multiple time of same version.