# How to deploy multiple instances of same webservice with different names on MSI installer

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-installer

I wish to deploy multiple instances of wcf webservice using MSI installer.When i tried deploying the same webservice i got error message saying I cannot install while there was an existing application on same name.

FYI, The reason why i am trying to install the same webservice twice because I have several applications that consumes this webservices.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to allow users to install multiple copies of an MSI file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732220/how-to-allow-users-to-install-multiple-copies-of-an-msi-file)

Comment: dont consider this as duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it a way to deploy the same webservice multiple times. You can create multiple setup projects with different names.In the same way you can setup the existing wcf service using the separate setup project.